# how to fix error "called incorrectly, should not be accessed directly"?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, order

Recently my woocommerce has been throwing errors all of a sudden. no changes were made to the website or server.

When customers try to run a transaction, they get the following error `"Transaction Failed. There was a problem running your transaction. C: nonp"`
I have no idea what "C: nonp" means. I have never seen this error before!

I check my error log afterwards and found a bunch of fields errors were called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly. As seen below;

> [31-Jul-2018 19:28:51 UTC] order_total was called incorrectly. Order
>   properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace:
>   require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax,
>   do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout,
>   WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment,
>   woocommerce_pnpdirect->process_payment,
>   WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was
>   added in version 3.0. [31-Jul-2018 19:28:51 UTC] billing_email was
>   called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly.
>   Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax,
>   do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout,
>   WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment,
>   woocommerce_pnpdirect->process_payment,
>   WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was
>   added in version 3.0. [31-Jul-2018 19:28:51 UTC] billing_address_1 was
>   called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly.
>   Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax,
>   do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout,
>   WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment,
>   woocommerce_pnpdirect->process_payment,
>   WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was
>   added in version 3.0. [31-Jul-2018 19:28:51 UTC] billing_address_2 was
>   called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly.
>   Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax,
>   do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout,
>   WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment,
>   woocommerce_pnpdirect->process_payment,
>   WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was
>   added in version 3.0. [31-Jul-2018 19:28:51 UTC] billing_postcode was
>   called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly.
>   Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax,
>   do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout,
>   WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment,
>   woocommerce_pnpdirect->process_payment,
>   WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was
>   added in version 3.0. [31-Jul-2018 19:28:51 UTC] billing_city was
>   called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly.
>   Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax,
>   do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout,
>   WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment,
>   woocommerce_pnpdirect->process_payment,
>   WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was
>   added in version 3.0. [31-Jul-2018 19:28:51 UTC] billing_state was
>   called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly.
>   Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax,
>   do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout,
>   WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment,
>   woocommerce_pnpdirect->process_payment,
>   WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was
>   added in version 3.0. [31-Jul-2018 19:28:51 UTC] billing_country was
>   called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly.
>   Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax,
>   do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout,
>   WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment,
>   woocommerce_pnpdirect->process_payment,
>   WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was
>   added in version 3.0. [31-Jul-2018 19:28:51 UTC] shipping_first_name
>   was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed
>   directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax,
>   do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout,
>   WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment,
>   woocommerce_pnpdirect->process_payment,
>   WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was
>   added in version 3.0. [31-Jul-2018 19:28:51 UTC] shipping_last_name
>   was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed
>   directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax,
>   do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout,
>   WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment,
>   woocommerce_pnpdirect->process_payment,
>   WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was
>   added in version 3.0. [31-Jul-2018 19:28:51 UTC] shipping_address_1
>   was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed
>   directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax,
>   do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout,
>   WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment,
>   woocommerce_pnpdirect->process_payment,
>   WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was
>   added in version 3.0. [31-Jul-2018 19:28:51 UTC] shipping_address_2
>   was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed
>   directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax,
>   do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout,
>   WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment,
>   woocommerce_pnpdirect->process_payment,
>   WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was
>   added in version 3.0. [31-Jul-2018 19:28:51 UTC] shipping_postcode was
>   called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly.
>   Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax,
>   do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout,
>   WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment,
>   woocommerce_pnpdirect->process_payment,
>   WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was
>   added in version 3.0. [31-Jul-2018 19:28:51 UTC] shipping_postcode was
>   called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly.
>   Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax,
>   do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout,
>   WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment,
>   woocommerce_pnpdirect->process_payment,
>   WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was
>   added in version 3.0. [31-Jul-2018 19:28:51 UTC] shipping_state was
>   called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly.
>   Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax,
>   do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout,
>   WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment,
>   woocommerce_pnpdirect->process_payment,
>   WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was
>   added in version 3.0. [31-Jul-2018 19:28:51 UTC] shipping_country was
>   called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly.
>   Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'),
>   require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
>   do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax,
>   do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), WP_Hook->do_action,
>   WP_Hook->apply_filters, call_user_func_array, WC_AJAX::checkout,
>   WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment,
>   woocommerce_pnpdirect->process_payment,
>   WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was
>   added in version 3.0.

Please help. I have been trying to fix this issue by checking pluggins, updates, cache, nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue. it was coming from the credit card processor. Our credit card was expired and account wasn't updated, so they disabled our account, not allowing us to process transactions through their gateway.

The company we use is Plug n Pay

The error ending with "C: nonp" represents "non-payment".

Hope this helps someone else who runs into this.